# Mapbox GL regex in Json

Tags: json, regex, mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js

I'm trying to only draw contour lines at every 30m of elevation. In mapbox studio this is pretty easy to do using the regex:

```
[ele =~ '.*30'] ...
```

Now I'm trying to do this using Mapbox GL which uses JSON, and I can't find any documentation on doing this.

```
{ 
"id": "contour_line_30s_over_2000m", 
"type": "line", 
"source": "mapbox", 
"source-layer": "contour", 
"filter": [">", "ele", 2000], //only show elevations over 2000m
"paint": { "line-color": "@contour_line_color" } 
}
```

What is the proper syntax for doing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Mapbox GL styles don't currently support using regular expressions in filters. See [this issue](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-style-spec/issues/233) for the feature request.